# python between modules import error

Tags: python, import, module

directory hierarchy:

```
 ---src
        ---WebService
              ---Model
                    ---BaseModel.py
                    ---ServiceAttribute.py
                    ---__init__.py
              ---ServiceImpl
                    ---Test.py
                    ---__init__.py
        ---__init__.py
 ---__init__.py
```

This is the construct of my project, and i want to import the `Model/ServiceAttribute.py` to `ServiceImpl/Test.py`,  and I do as follows:

```
from src.WebService.Model.ServiceAttribute import ServiceAttribute
```

But I was told that there is an `importError` in my code:

```
 src.WebService.Model.ServiceAttribute.ServiceAttrbute is not a module.
```

How to solve this problem? Need your help!

Comment: Why is `src` a package at all here? I'd expect you to import `WebService.Model.ServiceAttribute` instead, where `src` is on your `sys.path`.

Comment: Your diagram is unclear; is there a `__init__.py` in `WebService`?

Comment: src is a package i created in the project.

Comment: But `src` is normally the name of the source directory, not a Python package. The top-level package here is `WebService`.

Comment: there do is a __init__.py in WebService, thanks

Comment: That sentence makes no sense. Do you mean "There is *no* `__init__.py` in `WebService`", or "There *is* a `__init__.py` in `WebService`".

Comment: (I love it when they do this.)

Answer (score 0):

If you import from `src.....` **then** you should run you `ServiceImpl/Test.py` like this: `python -m src.WebService. ServiceImpl.Test` in src's parent directory